# String Manipulation/Errors in C++ using IOStream

Tags: c++

Could someone explain the difference between these 2 lines of code in C++? I get an output very different than I anticipated

```
string s1 = 'abcd'

string s2 = 'ef'
```

**First Input: Incorrect**

input:

```
cout << s1.size() + " " + s2.size() << endl;
```

output : ; D

**Second Input: Correct**

input:

```
cout << s1.size() << " " << s2.size() << endl;
```

output : 4 2

I compiled it and ran it off the HackerRank servers for one of the challenges and was not sure why the results were different.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] reproducing your problem please. As is your question is useless.

Comment: You're using integer addition in the first one... what kind of result would you expect? :)

Comment: Please post the code, if you want any answer. What ever you posted is incomplete and it is very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When initializing a `std::string` variable, use `"` (double quotes), not `'` (single quote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot implicitly add a `std::size_t` variable to a `const char*` (i.e. the `" "` in your code) and achieve the desired result, you would have to do:

```
std::cout << std::to_string(s1.size()) + " " + std::to_string(s2.size()) << std::endl;
```

(i.e. convert the `std::size_t` values to strings first and then concatenate with a space).

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I keep using Python for creating my scripts, so I am used to the compiler understanding different data types in a print statement.